# Microsoft Access - Saving New Record to Linked Database

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am creating a user interface based off of one internal and two linked (external) Access datasheets in Access 2013.

Two of the fields on my UI are combo boxes that read from the linked datasheets and display the options. This is so that the entries for suppliers and material types are called-out consistently and typos are avoided. However, I would like to add the following functionality:

-If a new value is entered into the combo box the user will be prompted to fill out the necessary information on the new value. This information will subsequently be saved to the appropriate linked datasheet.

How would I go about setting up the prompt from the combo boxes themselves? It would require Access to open a form or sub-form that will, in turn, save to the linked datasheet.

I'd prefer it to be automatic, instead of end-user prompted so that it isn't skipped. It's been years since I played around with VB, so I would like to avoid that if possible and use Access' built-in functions (even if it requires a little more time). Thank you in advance!

Comment: External datasheet means? Excel?

Comment: No, an external Access datasheet. I'll update my original post.

Comment: Can you use this? [ComboBox.NotInList Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845736.aspx)

Comment: if its linked table, you can treat as own table and as hansup suggested use the notInList event to add the item.

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I was able to do it after researching the "OnNotInList" function and a little VB code.

In the OnNotInList section of the 'Event' properties sheet, I chose 'Code Builder' and entered the following:

```
Private Sub Supplier_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim ctl As Control
Dim dbsCustomerDatabase As Database

On Error GoTo Supplier_NotInList_Err
Dim intAnswer As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
intAnswer = MsgBox("The supplier " & Chr(34) & NewData & _
    Chr(34) & " is not currently listed." & vbCrLf & _
    "Would you like to add it to the list now?" _
    , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Spire Manufacturing Solutions")
' Adding the new entry to the list:
If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO CustomerList([CustomerName]) " & _
             "VALUES ('" & NewData & "');"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "The new supplier has been added to the list." _
        , vbInformation, "Spire Manufacturing Solutions"
    Response = acDataErrAdded
' Opening the Supplier datasheet to add details 
' to the new entry:
    MsgBox "Opening Supplier database for new entry..."
    DoCmd.OpenTable "CustomerList", acViewNormal, acEdit

End If
Supplier_NotInList_Exit:
Exit Sub
Supplier_NotInList_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
Resume Supplier_NotInList_Exit
End Sub
```

This allowed me to automatically prompt the user to add the details for a new supplier if they enter a new supplier name. Or, cancel the entry if they simply misspelled it. I'd quite forgotten how versatile VB was. Thank you all for your assistance in getting me headed in the right direction!

Comment: If you replace `DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL` with `CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError`, you can avoid `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.  Turning `SetWarnings` off suppresses information which can be vital for trouble-shooting.